# Broken Connector

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I was trying to get my GPU out of my PC, forgot that you had to push a tab to get it out correctly, in the process of freak out and then getting it out I found that just one of the connectors is scratched off.

[image]

I was wondering if I have to end up buying a whole new GPU or the damage isn't too great since its just one connector and I can just keep on using.

Edit: Booted up with some funky colors on my monitor for a second or two but that's about it, works just fine.

Comment: If you keep on using it, does it still work? If so, keep using it. If not, you may be able to fix it. Great profile picture btw.

Comment: Which GPU are we talking about? We may be able to figure out what the pin is supposed to do. Is the card under warranty?

Comment: It is possible to repair (but that is not super easy), but if it works it works and I wouldn't bother https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/7a6pqm/comment/dp7jw17/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: The GPU is a XFX RX580 GTS XXX and it doesn't have a warranty, it came from a janky prebuilt, doesn't even have the fans it would come with.

Comment: And does it work if you stick it in the pc? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Pinout

Comment: You should verify that the connector is actually damaged. Wouldn’t be the first to misidentify a damaged PCIe connector

Comment: According to Google Images there is a bit of damage, but I wouldn't be surprised at all if it still worked.

Comment: It should be ok, just have to touch the PCIe slot's pin to make contact. Look like it has enough surface. Repairing it would require some skills and tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact spec for PCIe, but it's not unusual to have half-length contacts on such as graphics cards - it prevents early contact if they are ever plugged live.

[image]

On your picture, though there is some apparent scratching above the pin end, the end itself looks square.. which would indicate this is intentional.

Also, if you look at the line of wear indicated by the arrow, that's where the contacts reach to when the connector is fully inserted. You might try cleaning that up - gently - with a cotton bud & some contact cleaner.

[image]

USB does the same - two short pins to prevent data from being connected before power.

[image]